linq join two datatables
I am trying to join two datatables with linq
The query is
out_dt = (From row1 in dt1, row2 in dt2
where row1("id").ToString = row2("id").ToString
Select row1).CopyToDatatable

Except now I realize that I also need a column from table dt2
So, how do I modify the select statment to get a row1, and a column from dt2, say row2("col2")
I can do it with a loop after the query but the table has thousands of columns and the query already lasts a long time to run so I would like to do this in one step
Much obliged

For performance purposes you should set PrimaryKey property on DataTables.

you simply ask for it. You can shape the resulting return object via the linq query in the Select command. Including renaming columns. Now, out_dt has to support the resulting dataset properly, but that's outside the scope here.
out_dt = (From row1 in dt1, row2 in dt2
        where row1("id").ToString = row2("id").ToString
        Select row1Id =row2.Id, row2ID = row2.Id).CopyToDatatable

Now, this is an implicit join, so you may want to have an explicit one instead:
out_dt = (From row1 in dt1
        Join row2 in dt2 on row2.Id equals row1.Id
        Select row1Id =row2.Id, row2ID = row2.Id).CopyToDatatable


I tried the first query and it works, except the CopyToDatatable, method, because the query returns an enumerable type that doesn't have that method, but I can live with a for loop to populate a datatable afterwards

Linq allows returning anonymous objects from a join. This is not of type IEnumerable<DataRow> so the CopyToDataTable() extension method will not work. But the following example will return the row1 and the extra column from the matched row2, as you requested.
Dim results = dt1.AsEnumerable().Join(
    dt2.AsEnumerable(),
    Function(r1) r1.Field(Of Integer)("id"),
    Function(r2) r2.Field(Of Integer)("id"), 
    Function(r1, r2) New With 
    { 
       Key.Row1 = r1, 
       Key.Col2 = r2.Field(Of String)("col2")
    })

